# Include formatting related guidelines in the Stack Exchange network sites

Tags: discussion

> - Short (Small) - Minimize bandwidth for your example, do not bore the audience.
> - Self Contained - Ensure everything is included, ready to go.
> - Correct - Copy, paste, (compile,) see is the aim.
> - **Clean - proper formatting or at least something that has some scope to be formatted**
> - Example - Displays the problem you are trying to solve.

There are many questions which are posted with such terrible formatting that it would take ages to make them good enough for SO standards. We already have flags for moderator attention for such questions.

Should this guideline also be included in Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Seeing as the website http://sscce.org/ is the origin of the advice, this may make sense as an extra guidance on Stack Exchange sites, but possible not elsewhere.

Comment: Yes even that would be a good thing to do.

Comment: My point is that http://sscce.org is outside Stack Exchange control and probably that's a good thing.

Comment: Ok so I will rephrase the question to make a point to include in StackExchange sites